# How to get piece of information from url given

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi i have this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="">
        <title>Submit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
function show_alert() {
    alert("Animes score is: ");
}
</script>
    <div class=střed>
        <form>
        <div id="one"><input style="width: 500px" type="text" name="url" value="Enter myanimelist URL" onfocus="if (this.value=='Enter myanimelist URL') this.value='';"/></div>
        <div id="two"><input type="image" onclick="show_alert();" name="submit" src="/Button1.png" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i want to get from user's url (for example: https://myanimelist.net/anime/5114/Fullmetal_Alchemist__Brotherhood) the anime's score from page's html (this part: `<span itemprop="ratingValue">9.26</span>` - so in this case it would be 9.26) and show it in alert box (doesn't need to be alert box thought, just somehow show it to user). Thanks for any help.

Comment: As per your example (`https://myanimelist.net/anime/5114/Fullmetal_Alchemist__Brotherhood`), what part do you want to get? Is it `5114`?

Comment: Unless the page allows you to access the data with CORS, you are going to run into the same origin policy problem.

Comment: No, its 9.26 from html of the url.